# Cypher / Preventing shortestPath function to retrieve nodes that don't involve at least one traversed relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Regarding this excerpt of cyper request: 
(assuming `element` is a known node variable in the whole request)

```
MATCH p = shortestPath(element-[:LINKS*..3]-(user))
RETURN length(p)
```

Assuming that one `element` might be a `user`, how could I prevent retrieving in the result the `element` representing the user itself?

It would be cool if we could do:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath(element-[:LINKS*1..3]-(user))
RETURN length(p)
```

But it leads to this error:

```
shortestPath(...) does not support a minimal length
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((element)-[:LINKS*..3]-(user))
WHERE element <> user
RETURN length(p)
```

Comment: Cool, that was so simple ;) Thanks